# Laravel Resource Collection and Pagination

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having trouble bringing model data with pagination, when I return it without going through a resource to transform it, it returns the pagination metadata, but when I use the resource it gets lost, in this example the resource doesn't nothing more and just to illustrate

```
$clients = (new Client)->whereHasMorph('client', [ Person::class, Company::class ]);

$clients = clientResource::collection($clients->paginate());
return response()->json($clients);
```

```
class PessoaResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array|Arrayable|JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request): array|JsonSerializable|Arrayable
    {
        return parent::toArray($this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is: "Why is this behavior different?" It's seem to be because different methods are use to turn the data into JSON depending on how the class is used. When it's returned directly from the controller function, the `toArray` method is used. This method receives the request object as it's first parameter and can do things like detect the page being browsed by inspecting the query string ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results)). On the other hand, when using the `response()->json()` helper, the `toJson` method is called on the resource. This method doesn't accept a request object and simply converts the provided data to JSON without attaching any metadata.

Ultimately you don't need to use the helper function because the resource can be returned directly and the data and metadata will be serialized correctly.

```
$clients = (new Client)->whereHasMorph('client', [ Person::class, Company::class ]);

return clientResource::collection($clients->paginate());
```

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't even have enough reputation to flag a post. Or comment. Or Vote. Or anything but answer the question. Just trying to be helpful. I'll keep that in mind when I recover from losing reputation here.

Comment: @NateRooskie Now you do.